# HTML modal closing button not working + contents inside not aligning

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I checked similar questions, but the solutions suggested didn't work for me.

The problem is that my modal closing button is not working and the contents inside it is not aligning.
(Update: When I turned on the border, I found out that a weird square is taking the space below "X", but still can't figure out why)

I think both issues are somehow related, along with the padding at the top, but I can't figure it out. Any help will be so much appreciated.

[image]

```css
.mobile-menu {
  float: right;
  padding: 1.1em 0.6em 0.1em 0.9em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.mobile-menu-modal {
  z-index:3;
  display:none;
  padding-top:85px;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.mobile-menu-modal-content{
  margin-right:10%;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color:#fff;
  position:relative;
  padding:0;
  width:40%;
}

.mobile-menu-a {
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:1.2em;
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<a class="mobile-menu" onclick="document.getElementById('mobilemenu').style.display='block'">Menu Button
  <div id="mobilemenu" class="mobile-menu-modal">
    <div class="mobile-menu-modal-content">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('mobilemenu').style.display='none'" style="float:right;font-size:2em;cursor:pointer;">&times;</span>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div style="padding-top:5em">
        <a class="mobile-menu-a">200K+</a>
        <a class="mobile-menu-a">300K+</a>
        <a class="mobile-menu-a">400K+</a>
        <a class="mobile-menu-a">1M+</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Could you make a minimal reproducible example showing this issue in a code snippet?

Comment: Sure I will minimize the code snippet more. Please hold!

Comment: Just to be clear, a code snippet as in the code that can just be run here on stack overflow (since it's just html and css). This allows people answering to easily visualise the problem by running the code snippet, and edit the code snippet to provide a solution. There should be a button to insert snippet when you are editing the question.

Comment: if you could describe more in detail, what you mean with "is not aligning" I could potentially update my post below and help with that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should close your <a> tag after the text (at the point when everything you want to display on the main page is displayed). Then start a new container for everything you want to display when the button gets clicked.
Also try to avoid inline styles and use an additional css class for the close button.

```css
.mobile-menu {
  float: right;
  padding: 1.1em 0.6em 0.1em 0.9em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.mobile-menu-modal {
  z-index:3;
  display:none;
  padding-top:85px;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.mobile-menu-modal-content{
  margin-right:10%;
  margin-left: auto;
  background-color:#fff;
  position:relative;
  padding:0;
  width:40%;
}

.mobile-menu-a {
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:1.2em;
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.mobile-menu-modal .close-button {
  float: right;
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a class="mobile-menu" onClick="document.getElementById('mobilemenu').style.display='block'">Menu Button</a>
  <div id="mobilemenu" class="mobile-menu-modal">
    <div class="mobile-menu-modal-content">
      <span class="close-button" onClick="document.getElementById('mobilemenu').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div style="padding-top:5em">
        <a class="mobile-menu-a">200K+</a>
        <a class="mobile-menu-a">300K+</a>
        <a class="mobile-menu-a">400K+</a>
        <a class="mobile-menu-a">1M+</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Cobra_8. This solved my problem. 
In my actual code, I put an image inside <a> tag. Putting the modal div after </a> solved the issue! (aligning issue also solved with this)